# jQuery .on() troubles

Tags: jquery

Ok guys, I've used .on before quite successfully, however, this time it isn't working as expected, because it's not recognizing dynamic elements at all!

see issue by visiting http://www.MetalGains.com . Click "view demo" and just login with the demo credentials. If you click on a 'pencil" you'll see the edit functionality work.  However, if you add an asset, and then click on the pencil that was added, you'll see it doesn't work.

At some point this line of code is dynamically added:

```
 <div class='edit-item'><a name='"+$id+"' href='#add-asset-"+status+"' class='edit'></a></div>
```

the javascript I want to invoke is below. Mind you, it DOES work on page load, just not on anything dynamic. What am I missing?

```
$(".edit-item .edit").on('click', function(){
    return false;
  }).each(function(){
            $(this).fancybox({
             afterClose: function(){
            //we have to remove this class so that if someone tries to add a new asset it will use the 
            //add script and not the update script
            $(".asset-form").removeClass("update");
            //We need to set the values back to empty so that they aren't prepopulated when someone 
            //tries to add an asset later.
            $(".asset-form :input[name='type']").val("");
            $(".asset-form :input[name='year']").val("");
            $(".asset-form :input[name='quantity']").val("");
            $(".asset-form :input[name='ounces']").val("");
            $(".asset-form :input[name='paid']").val("");
            $(".asset-form :input[name='date']").val("");
            $(".asset-form :input[name='notes']").val("");

            //we remove the hidden field that passes the asset id. 
            $(".asset-form :input[name='editId']").remove();



            }//end afterClose
    }); //end edit fancybox
}); //end each
```

By the way, this works perfectly:

```
   $(".note-img").on('click', function(){
return false;
}).each(function(){
    $(this).fancybox();
    });
```

In relation to this dynamically added content:

```
   <a href='#note-"+$id+"' class='note-img'></a><div class='note' id='note-"+$id+"'>"+$notes+"</div>
```

Comment: put your return false at the end not at beginning, also for dynamic DOM use live http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: @JonathandeM. i might be wrong but i thing `on` calls `live` behind the scenes

Comment: @JonathandeM.: Since jQuery 1.7, [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) has been deprecated in favor of [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), which you would have known had you read [your own link](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Answer (score 4):

The correct way of using `on` for event delegation is:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit-item .edit', function(){
```

Or:

```
$('#staticParent').on('click', '.edit-item .edit', function(){
```

In case that the `edit-item` is static:

```
$('.edit-item').on('click', '.edit', function(){
```

Actually `on` differs from old and deprecated `live` method, `live` delegates the event from document object, but with `on` method you should specify *which static parent element* or *document object* should be used for event delegation.

Comment: Yes these all look reasonable but I can't get these examples to work for me :(  However, if you look at my edit above, I've included some example code that works perfectly. I use .on correctly in one instance but am failing on the second for some reason.

Comment: $('.edit-item').on('click', '.edit', function(){    

from your code above, works EXACTLY how mine does currently. Works great for non-dynamic elements.

Comment: @user1888959 Actually the event is delegated if you use proper element for delegation, the issue should be related to the logic of your click handler.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this problem before by adding a selector context to the end like so ...

```
$(".edit").on('click', '.edit-item', function(){ ... })};
```

Comment: Ah, I was thinking of `$('.edit').on({change: function(){ ... }},'.edit-item');` ... u are correct

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below code.

```
$('.edit-item').on('click', '.edit', function(){})
```